# Is there a way to see the temp, cache, directories while debugging iOS app?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Is there a way to see the temp, cache, directories while debugging an iOS app?

If I am not wrong, earlier versions of Xcode had that...

I am particularly interested in seeing the contents of NSApplicationSupportDirectory.

Comment: Your speed was inversely proportional to your accuracy. The link has nothing to do with what I have asked and the link shows stuff that is from 2011 that is not even present on Xcode today.

Comment: It seems your question was about the simulator and not a real iOS device, correct? Then you should make that clear. You tagged this question `iPad` and `iPhone`, not `ios-simulator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even now you can see the contents of temp, cache directories for debugging.. but the library folder is hidden now.. you can view the directories from the following path..

```
/Users/<user-name>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<iOS-version>/<app-identifier>/
```

I hope, I given answer for what you are expecting..

Comment: This is only for the simulator, not a real iOS device.

Comment: @rmaddy for real devices, you can see my response

Comment: I am on a MacBook Pro 16 2019, running macOS Catalina 10.15.7. Using Simulator iPhone 11 Pro - iOS 14. But I do not see any i any "iPhone Simulator" folder at the path: "/Users/<user-name>/Library/Application Support". Any idea where to find it in my environment?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252319/where-can-i-find-the-cached-images-path-when-i-use-the-cached-network-image-fl

Answer (score 8):

For real devices, you can do this downloading the "Container Folder", on xcode go to Window > Device and Simulators.

Select your app, and select "Download container", like this:

[image: example]

You will see the container, just open it with: "Show Package Contents", in this folder you can see, cache folder, UserDefaults etc.